# How to add LinkedIn to SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**How do I make a custom authentication provider like `LinkedIn` appear in `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()` from where `Login.cshtml` picks up by default**

**Background Details:**

I am trying to understand asp.net core identity framework. In that quest, I created a standard .net core project

[image: Project Type]

[image: Project Type]

I tried out the supported `Google` authentication alongside reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/) and it all worked fine for me.

I was able to make `LinkedIn` authentication work for me, but couldn't understand how to make certain pieces work. To add support for `LinkedIn` authentication, I made the following changes

Added the below lines In `Startup.Configure` method

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions() {
    AuthenticationScheme = "LinkedIn",
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientID"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientSecret"],
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin"),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
    TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
    UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)",
    Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" },
});
```

Added the required `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` to the configuration

Added the following line to the `Login.cshtml`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="LinkedIn" title="Log in using your LinkedIn account">LinkedIn</button>
```

All this works fine. Now my question is:
**For supported authentication providers, as soon as I call, say, `app.UseGoogleAuthentication` in `Startup.Configure`, my call to `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()` in `Login.cshtml` lists `Google` as a provider. What do I need to do, so the call to `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()` will also list `LinkedIn` as a provider**

Comment: I trust you have checked out https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-a-user-with-linkedin-in-aspnet-core/ ?

Comment: @GeoffJames Yes I did. It helped me understand bunch of things, but not this specific issue. The lack of formal documentation of the `asp.net core` Framework and related libraries like the `Identity` has been my biggest enemy

Comment: I thought you might have. Just thought I'd check. I agree, it seems there's not much on this topic. Only the usual "how to add auth providers..." stuff. I hope you get your issue sorted :) Happy coding!

Comment: `HttpContext.GetExternalProviders()` is supposed to return `IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription>`. Have you tried calling that in your Login controller to see if there is anything there for LinkedIn (or Google)? These should be in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication` namespace.

Comment: I don't see the function `HttpContext.GetExternalProviders()`. But thanks, it made me re-do my checks leading me to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to do, so the call to SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes() will also list LinkedIn as a provider

This method only lists the authentication middleware that have been assigned a "display name".

To include Linked in the providers list, set `OAuthOptions.DisplayName`:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions
{
    DisplayName = "LinkedIn"
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I already found the answer for this, but thanks for posting it for others benefit. I am surprised that there is no documentation saying this. I ended up browsing the github code to figure this out (since the core framework debugging is not really setup on my VS 2017). I wonder how you discovered that this is the issue?

Comment: @Vikhram haha. Well, I helped the ASP.NET team design this generic OAuth2 middleware so I know quite well how it works internally :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :)